# OpenCV: 4 camera Bird's Eye view?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, perspectivecamera

I am having quite a lot of trouble thinking of how to make a four camera bird's eye view like that [seen in luxury cars](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uh5aUJ4TMyc/maxresdefault.jpg). Here is the original that I will be using as an example for this question...[image]

Right now, I have made it so the image is skewed using `.getPerspectiveTransform` but that is just for one image.

[image]

I obviously need four and am clueless on how to stitch those images together. I am also clueless if this is how the images are supposed to look like. Here is the code I currently have:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img1 = cv.imread("testBird.jpg", cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
image = np.zeros((700, 700, 3), np.uint8)
src = np.array([[0,200],[480,200],[480,360],[0,360]],np.float32)
dst = np.array([[0,0],[480,0],[300,360],[180,360]],np.float32)

M = cv.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst)
warp = cv.warpPerspective(img1.copy(), M, (480, 360))
cv.imshow('transform', warp)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

and here is the end image that I would roughly like to have (A friend put together using Photoshop)...

[image]

Comment: Can you share the original images you want to stitch?

Comment: @FrancescoCallari Edited to show the original.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To implement the transform, you need to refer to the `getPerspectiveTransform` function. It takes:

- src:  Coordinates of quadrangle vertices in the source image.
- dst: Coordinates of the corresponding quadrangle vertices in the destination image.

  I think that it's not an easy problem to define "src" and "dst". It needs some computations based **on real-world data** and cannot be solved by itself, just by having a look at the pictures.

---

So for me, the key idea is **make a plan** of the desired scene (what it must look like). It should use real data such as:

- the distance between cameras
- the angle of view of the cameras
- the size of the rectangle between the cameras (the gray and white grid)

[image]

Then you can find a good value for the distance E-F depending on the size of the "viewport of your fictive bird's view camera". After that, your job is nearly done.

---

The `dst` parameter is simply **a scaled version of the rectangle** I J L K (for the upper camera). Depending on the size in pixel of the output image.

The `src` parameter should be a rectangle in your photograph. Its **width will fill the entire picture**. The **height must be computed from the E-F wanted distance**.

[image]

They are two ways to compute the height of the red rectangle. Either **you place "markers" on the real scene** (or you try to detect some) to automatically find a horizontal line. Or, you can try to compute it as a complex **function of the elevation angle of your camera** (but I want to advise you, I think it seems quite complicated).

Here's how I would have solved that problem. I hope it helped :)

Comment: That helped! I know need help with removing the black corners so when the images are put together, they are not overlapping. I made a new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276857/opencv-how-to-stitch-four-trapezoid-images-to-make-a-square-image