# Opencv: How to stitch four trapezoid images to make a square image?

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, opencv

I am currently trying very hard to figure out a way to make these four trapezoid images into one nice image. The final image should look something like this(used photoshop to make it):
[image]

That above image will be complied with four of these images:

[image]

The problem is that when I try to rotate and combine these images, the black surroundings come into the final image as well like this:

[image]

How am I supposed to rid of the blacked out area or make it transparent? I've tried using a mask but that only make the black area white instead. I have also tried using the alpha channel, but that didn't work(although maybe I was doing wrong). Any ideas on what I can do in OpenCV?

Comment: can you please show how you stitch the images together? You may simply check if the area is black when you put the images together.

Comment: @pyan I posted how I did it. Thanks!

Comment: I am working on a similar project. Can you please guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did actually figure it out. I did it with these steps:

- Create two SAME SIZED black backgrounds with numpy zeros
- Put one image in each background where you want them(for me, it was left and top)
- Then all you need to do is cv.add(first, second)

The reason it works is because black pixels are 0,0,0 so adding to a pixel that is, say, 25,62,34, the pixel doesn't change and thus rids of the black corner.